# SQL Agent Job Close Excel Process

Tags: sql, excel, vbscript, agent

I would like to create a SQL job that will close any excel processes opened. I've created a VB Script that works on double-click. I've tried

`wscript C:\Apps\DestroyExcel.vbs`

using type CmdExec. How can I execute it form SQL to schedule the job to run?

```
Dim objXL
On Error Resume Next
Set objXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

If Not TypeName(objXL) = "Empty" Then
    objXL.quit
Else
    msgbox "Excel Not Running."
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS:

1. Go to SQL Server Agent
2. Right-click "Jobs" --> New Job
3. Enter info
4. In the steps section, click New
5. For the Type, choose Operating Sytem (CmdExex)
6. For the command, type: cscript C:\myscript.vbs
7. Set your schedule
8. Press OK

I believe that should do it.

Comment: I've tried that option. It executes successfully with no errors, but Excel is still open. Maybe I should try Master.XP_CMDSHELL

Comment: @g_shockTan that's interesting. maybe it's a permissions thing? I think the SQL job runs from the SQL Server agent by default which might not have sufficient permission to run the vbs script...hmmmm

Comment: I executed it in cmd prompt and works using cscript c:\apps\destroyexcel.vbs enter. It closed all excel process.

Comment: @g_shockTan it has to be a permissions issue then. the SQL Server Agent doesn't have enough privileges to execute the statements in the vbscript. let me see what i can figure out

Comment: @g_shockTan after a lot of digging, i'm at a complete loss :( I cannot, for the life of me, get this to work on my PC. I tried a bunch of things (batch files, new users, proxies with credentials) but ultimately I can't get it to work. I would love to find out how you or anyone else solves this problem. sorry g_shockTan